# Creating a custom token that gets value of node fields

Tags: 7, tokens

new to Drupal / PHP.

What I'd like to do is get the value of a couple fields from a node. Then create a custom token from them so I can use them in the meta tag module.  Or just get the value of a node token that's already been created.

I'm not really sure where to start, does this need to happen in the node template or a module?

At the moment I am using the following code to create a module that creates a custom token.

```
<?php


/**
 * Implements hook_token_info().
 */
function globalpost_custom_token_info() {
  $info = array();
  // Define a new token type.
  $info['types']['gp_tokens'] = array(
    'name' => t('GlobalPost Custom Tokens'),
    'description' => t('A token type for GlobalPost tokens.'),
  );
  // Define any new tokens.
  $info['tokens']['gp_tokens']['gp_keywords'] = array(
    'name' => t('GlobalPost Keywords'),
    'description' => t('A list of formated keywords for metatags'),
  );
  return $info;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_tokens().
 */
function globalpost_custom_tokens($type, $tokens, array $data = array(), array $options = array()) {
  $replacements = array();

  if ($type == 'gp_tokens') {
    // Loop through the available tokens.
    foreach ($tokens as $name => $original) {
      // Find our custom tokens by name.
      switch ($name) {
        case 'gp_keywords':
          // Work out the value of our token.
          $value = "CAN I PUT ANOTHER NODE TOKEN HERE OR DATA FROM NODE's FIELD?" ;
          // Give our token it's value!
          $replacements[$original] = $value;
          break;
      }
    }
  }

  return $replacements;
}



?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! This might help you: see [Examples](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples) module, specifically the `token_example`.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that the example module for token does a check on the body using field_get_items();

I tried to grab my subhead field using the same function, then pass it to the token:

$output= field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_subhead');
$replacements[$original] = $output;

But I just get an empty value.